# Does $f=g_1^{n_1}\cdots g_k^{n_k}$ imply $\operatorname{Gal}(f)=\operatorname{Gal}(g_1)\times\cdots\times\operatorname{Gal}g_k)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-groups, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $f=g_1^{n_1}\cdots g_k^{n_k}$ where $g_1,\cdots, g_k$ are distinct irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. Whether does it hold
$\operatorname{Gal}(f)=\operatorname{Gal}(g_1)\times\cdots\times \operatorname{Gal}(g_k)$? Thank you a lot.

Is this right or wrong? How to prove? (we may also add some conditions if cannot prove)

Comment: For this to hold the splitting fields of the factors $g_i,i=1,2,\ldots,k,$ need to be linearly disjoint in the stronger sense that the splitting fields of products of any two disjoint sets of factors should be linearly disjoint. Equivalently, if $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ and $K_i$ the splitting field of $g_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, then
$$[K:\Bbb{Q}]=\prod_{i=1}^k[K_i:\Bbb{Q}].$$
This follows by induction on $k$ using the lemma that if $K_1,K_2$ are linearly disjoint Galois extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, then $Gal(K_1K_2/\Bbb{Q})\cong Gal(K_1/\Bbb{Q})\times Gal(K_1/\Bbb{Q}).$

Comment: That first comment became a bit unclear after hasty editing. The point was that if the condition on the degrees of the splitting fields holds, then so does the claim about the structure of the Galois group.

Answer (score 8):

No, not necessarily. Try, for instance, $g_1 = x^2 + 2$, $g_2 = x^2 - 2$, $g_3 = x^2 + 1$. Note that $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, i) = \mathbb Q(i, \sqrt{2})$.